# check each string numbers by Recursion

Tags: javascript, arrays, recursion

how to check each substring until numbers what we want to create on a new array or new string variable? I just want to know how to recursion work to check them 
let's say that i have a function to find the odd numbers and length

```
function findOdd(num){

};
findOdd(23478); // 3 and 7
findOdd(2468); // no numbers


function lengthOdd(arr){

};
lengthOdd(["Mike","Johny","David"]); // ["Johny", "David"];
lengthOdd(["Tonnies","Don"]) // [Tonnies","Don"]
```

Comment: Please share the attempted code.

Comment: can't see a strong reason for using recursion here

Comment: i just want to know how to recursion here

Answer (score 2):

This can also be achieved without `recursion` using `Array.filter`. Pls see below

```js
function findOdd(num){
  return [...num.toString()].filter(d => d%2 != 0).map(Number)
};

console.log(findOdd(23478))
console.log(findOdd(2468))
```

```js
function lengthOdd(arr){
  return arr.filter(d => d.length %2 != 0)
};

console.log(lengthOdd(["Mike","Johny","David"]))
```

Answer (score 0):

While there is no need to use recursion here, a good general guideline for recursion is:

- a solid base case
- solving smaller subproblems with faith that our recursive function works if it's not the base case

So applying this for this for `findOdd` we have the following:

```js
function findOdd(num){
   // base case
  if (num < 10) return num % 2 === 0 ? [] : [num];
  
  // combine smaller subproblems
  var sn = '' + num;
  return findOdd(parseInt(sn[0])).concat(findOdd(parseInt(sn.slice(1))));
};

console.log(findOdd(23478));
console.log(findOdd(2468));
```

You can do something similar for `lengthOdd`.